# overlay support in windows/opengl environment

Tags: opengl, overlays

I have to display an image and text overlay, when text overlay contains many strings, but only one changes from frame to frame. I want to avoid redraw of the entire overlay and only update what has changed.

I tried wglCreateLayerContext but my GPU seems to not support it (PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR bReserved is 0).

What is the most efficient way to redraw only part of text overlay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redrawing the whole framebuffer is the canonical way in OpenGL. You can use Framebuffer Objects (FBO) to create several off-screen drawing surfaces, to which you render the individual layers. Then you composit the layers into a composite image presented on screen.

> but only one changes from frame to frame. I want to avoid redraw of the entire overlay

Why? Figuring out what parts need redraw, masking them, do only a partial clear, updating it, etc. takes more time and effort than to simply redraw the whole text overlay.

Comment: The rendering performance I measured is about 50 mksec per string. This is too much. Years ago when working on GDI systems (unix,  opengl), I used to redraw only modified strings with XOR (to erase previous rendering result) and then rendered new string value. It was fast (then). Now I have to do something similar on windows with every frame computed with OpenCL and rendered with OpenGL, with text overlay on top.
The performance I measured above is with  
    glListBase(1000);
    glRasterPos2f(-0.9f, 0.8f); 
 glCallLists (strsz, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, str);

Comment: @user2156173: I take it your nonconformant prefix "mk" stands for "micro" or 10^-6. You can write this either as µ or, if you can't find it on your keyboard as "u". Anyway, instead of thinking "how can't I avoid that redraw", you should think: *"How can I make my text render faster?!"* So here's the big question: Which method do you use to render your text? I bet it can be optimized, a lot!

Comment: Current attepmt which I measured for 50µms is direct rendering of all the text overlay (for every frame) as:  
    glListBase(1000);  
    glRasterPos2f(-0.9f, 0.8f);  
    glCallLists (strsz, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, str);  
No bitmap or rendering into texture was used.  

Is it the most efficient way to do it?... For now, I'm lost a bit which way to go/research, for example GDI+ also provides some capabilities... (Btw, code formatting with 4 indent spaces here doesn't work from some reasone)

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't need 3D stunts. Simply (well... simply) and fast redraw the text overlay over image frame rendered by OpenCL.

Comment: OpenGL raster ops tend to be quite slowish. Layered contexts are available only with special GPUs. You won't find support for this kind of OpenGL overlay on the average GPU, so I'd not invest time in that. The easiest and fastest way actually is using a FBO to render the text into a texture and then overlay this over the image. However, as I said, OpenGL raster ops can be quite slow and you may get a much better performance by using texture mapped fonts. As sad as it is, but OpenGL and text rendering always has been a tricky issue.